# How can I clear the random quotes output field?

Tags: javascript

I've made a random quote generator, it works properly with the only drawback - first quote is done, I click for the next one, it begins to appear in the output field, but the previous quote is still here(
I've tried location.reload(), but it simply keeps my output clean.
Please, advice, how can I fix that?

```
var source,
    adress,
    source_length,
    start = 0,   
    randNum;
var quotes[some, examples, inside, etc];    

 function flowText(){

    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
    source = quotes[randNum];
    console.log(source);        
    adress = document.getElementById('wind');       
    source_length = source.length;      
    flow();
    //location.reload();        
 }
  function flow(){
    adress.innerHTML += source.substr(start, 1);
    start+=1;
    if(start < source_length){
        setTimeout("flow()", 100);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `adress.innerHTML +=` -> `adress.innerHTML =`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want adress to retain the previous quote

```
adress.innerHTML = '';
```

Then call flow();